# Can we invoke a class constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, terminology

I have 2 sets of lecture notes. One refer a constructor as a form of method. The other set of notes claimed that constructors are not method.

Personally I felt that constructors are not methods. But am I correct to use the term `invoke` on a `constructor`?

**My question is:** We can invoke a java method. But am I correct to say "invoke a constructor" ?

---

I visited this site:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html
It looks inappropriate to use the term `invoke` on constructors?

Comment: This is just arguing semantics.  But FWIW, the JLS talks about "invoking constructors" (e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8).

Comment: You don't invoke constructors like normal methods but operator `new` invokes it.

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam Webster describes `invoke` like this:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invoke)

> : to mention (someone or something) in an attempt to make people feel a certain way or have a certain idea in their mind
>
> : to refer to (something) in support of your ideas
>
> : to make use of (a law, a right, etc.)

So yes, I would say you can invoke a constructor much like you can invoke a method. But as [the java specifcation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8) says

> Constructors are never invoked by method invocation expressions

so constructors can only be invoked by creating an object:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class InvokeConstructor {

    public InvokeConstructor() {
        System.out.println("constructor1");
    }

    public InvokeConstructor(final boolean unused) {
        System.out.println("constructor2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new InvokeConstructor();
        new InvokeConstructor(false);

        // And using reflection:
        try {
            Constructor<InvokeConstructor> constructor1 = InvokeConstructor.class.getConstructor();
            constructor1.newInstance();
            Constructor<InvokeConstructor> constructor2 = InvokeConstructor.class.getConstructor(Boolean.TYPE);
            constructor2.newInstance(Boolean.FALSE);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  // TODO: implement catch
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  // TODO: implement catch
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  // TODO: implement catch
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  // TODO: implement catch
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is a method, which has some **special privileges** such as-
1. We can't use any return type with it as implicitly constructor returns the reference of the object when invoked along with **"new"** keyword.
2.The name should always be same as class name.
3. We can't use any access specifier for constructor.

So,you can say **"invoke a constructor"**.

For more detail you can refer this link- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: *"We can't use any access specifier for constructor as implicitly it is static."* This isn't true and I don't see where you could get it from.